# Dart : Read annotated value of a field

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Dart enum which looks like this:

```
enum Gender {
  @JsonValue(0)
  male,
  @JsonValue(1)
  female,
}
```

I have created a dart extension that returns the String name and int value. It looks something like this -

```
extension GenderExtention on Gender {
  String get name {
    switch (this) {
      default:
        return _getDefaultName(this);
    }
  }

  //For the enum male, it returns "Male"
  String _getDefaultName(Community value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }
    String valueStr = value.toString();
    String enumName = valueStr.substring(valueStr.indexOf('.') + 1);
    return enumName[0].toUpperCase() + enumName.substring(1);
  }

  int get value {
    switch (this) {
      case Gender.male:
        return 0;
      case Gender.female:
        return 1;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

This becomes painful for larger enums, especially the value section.

Are there any suggestions on how to get the enum value (0 for @JsonValue(0)) more easily than manually defining it in the extension? Would using something like reflections help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to access annotations at run-time is indeed reflection using `dart:mirrors`. That library is not available when compiling to the web or for Flutter, so it's probably not going to solve your problem.

What you can do *here* is:

```dart
  int get value => this.index;
```

That only works if the values are actually the same as the index (0 for the first declared value, 1 for the next, etc.)

Comment: ya, thats unfortunate. Using index feels a little weird as an accidental re order could mess things up. Anyways, thank you for taking the time to answer :)